# How does a binary search tree object print every element using recursion in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def _append(self, value):

        self.root = self._appending(self.root, value)

    def _appending(self, node, value):
        if not node:
            node = Node(value)
        elif value > node.value:
            node.left = self._appending(node.left, value)
            print("==============",node.left.value)
        else:
            node.right = self._appending(node.right, value)
            print("--------------",node.right.value)
        return node

    def print_tree(self):
        if self.root is None:
            print("Binary tree is empty")
            return
        self._print_tree_recursive(self.root)

    def _print_tree_recursive(self, node):
        if node is None:
            return
        self._print_tree_recursive(node.right)
        print(node.value, end=" ")
        self._print_tree_recursive(node.left)


# Create an instance of BinaryTree
tree = BinaryTree()

# Add nodes to the binary tree
tree._append(1)
tree._append(2)
tree._append(-1)
tree._append(100)
tree._append(1)

# Print the binary tree
tree.print_tree()
```

i need to know how it print every elements. To be more clear

```
 def _print_tree_recursive(self, node):
        if node is None:
            return
        self._print_tree_recursive(node.right)
        print(node.value, end=" ")
        self._print_tree_recursive(node.left)
```

while it hits the line `self._print_tree_recursive(node.right)` it print -1 but how it manages to go back to the node which contains value 1 also -1's node.right and node.left is none. so how other values are printed

```
                                          1
                                         / \
                                       -1   2
                                             \
                                             100
                                               \
                                                1
```

when it reaches the node -1 how it can go back node 1.***can you please explain it clearly as i am a beginner***

Comment: The caller of the function will resume with the rest of the code once the called function returns.

Comment: You need to keep the *definition* of the function distinct from any particular *call* to the function. It's defined once, but there can be multiple active instances of that function on the call stack at any given time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine you have this binary search tree:

```
                  D
              B       F
            A   C   E   G
```

An inorder traversal of the tree will return the nodes in order: A,B,C,D,E,F,G

The typical recursive algorithm is:

```
inorder(node)
    if (node == null)
        return
    inorder(node.left)
    print node.value
    inorder(node.right)
    return
```

One way of viewing things is in a hierarchy, with indentation at each recursive call. For example, below is the order of calls that occur after you make the initial call that passes the root (a reference to node `D`). At each indentation level, the return address and current `node` value are pushed onto the stack. And on return the most recently pushed values are popped from the stack:

```
inorder(D) 
    inorder(B)             // D.left
        inorder(A)         // B.left
            inorder(null)  // A.left
                return
            print A
            inorder(null)  // A.right
                return
            return
        print B
        inorder(C)         // B.right
            inorder(null)  // C.left
                return
            print C
            inorder(null)  // C.right
                return
        return
    print D
    inorder(F)             // D.right
        inorder(E)         // F.left
            inorder(null)  // E.left
                return
            print E
            inorder(null)  // E.right
                return
            return
        print F
        inorder(G)         // F.right
            inorder(null)  // G.left
                return
            print G
            inorder(null)  // G.right
                return
            return
         return
    return
```